# The local repository is out of date. Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am new to Git and I am trying to merge my branch (`With_Base_Class`) with the remote master branch from within Xcode.

I tried commiting and pulling in every possible order (I hope), but every time I recieve the following error:

```
The local repository is out of date. 
Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again.
```

This is a video of me getting the error:

https://youtu.be/sEfSnnHONkU

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run the `git status` command in the terminal inside your repository and see what it says?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: It seemed you executed a git pull from the menus, but what happen if you execute `git pull` on the command line? Does it say anything?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen After writing the comment, I made a pull from With_base_class from XCode (maybe it had an effect). After typing git pull, the result is: Already up-to-date.

Comment: When you executed that `git pull`, were you on branch master or With_base_class ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen On branch With_base_class

Comment: But it is branch master you're having problems with, and that you executed `git status` for. So checkout master, then do a git pull, all from the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141922/discussion-between-toma-radu-petrescu-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Answer (score 37):

Try this git command

git push origin master --force

Comment: best answer and should be at top

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to KinneyKare's answer, I tried simply shutting down and restarting Xcode. This worked! If you get the

> The local repository is out of date.

error in Xcode, I suggest first trying to simply exiting/shutting down/and restarting Xcode.  (aka: throw the big red switch if all else fails).

Comment: This case worked for me. Need to close the xcode app completely.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue and it ended up being a weird disconnect between Xcode and GitHub. How I fixed this was going to GitHuB and changing my password. Then authenticating again in Xcode using the new password. WORKED LIKE A CHARM!!!

Comment: Wow! This solution worked for me too! In my case, Xcode was also telling me that my local repository was out of date, yet when I did `git pull` from the command line, I got a message saying "Already up to date." (I also did source control > pull... from the menu bar in Xcode). However when I logged out and back in again, the problem was fixed. You would never think that this would work, yet it did.

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin NameBarche --force
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

Try use Merge "main" into "main"

[image]